# Add project JAR to deployment assembly but not build path in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee

Eclipse automatically adds everything in WEB-INF/lib (specified in deployment assembly) to the project's build path. Is there a way to override this behavior? I need for another project jar to be deployed and available at run time but not have a forced compile-time dependency on it. Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean another project as a jar, or a jar from another project when you say, "project jar"?

Comment: Another project as a jar. Normally you would just add a project to the deployment assembly, but in this case I want it deployed but not have a forced dependency on it.

Comment: What's the runtime dependency on it, then?

Comment: I need it on classpath so I can load a class from it.

Comment: The scenario should not be uncommon. Project A (dynamic web) defines interface I; project B (utility) depends on A and defines class C that implements I. Code in A instantiates C reflectively by name (from metadata) and casts it to I. A knows nothing about B. Forcing B on the build path for A creates a circular dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the properties window of the project. Then go to java build path tab and remove the relevant other project from libraries there. Then go to projects in the same tab and select the required project by using the add option and add it.  Then restart Eclipse.

Comment: "restart VS code" for an eclipse question...?

Comment: Sorry my mistake. I edited it.